# If $(f,g)$ and $(f,h)$ are maximal ideals, then $ag+bh=P(f)$ for some $a,b \in k, P(t) \in k[t]$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, for example $k=\mathbb{C}$.
Let $f,g,h \in k[x,y]$, $g \neq h$, satisfy the following two conditions:
(1) $(f,g)$ is a maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$;
(2) $(f,h)$ is a maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$.

**Claim 1:** There exist $a,b \in k$, at least one of $\{a,b\}$ is nonzero, and $P(t) \in k[t]$ such that
$ag+bh=P(f)$.

> **Question 1:** Is claim 1 true?

An example where claim 1 holds:
$f=x+y,g=5x+3y,h=4x+y$. We can take $a=-3,b=2, P(t)=-7t$ and get:
$-3(5x+3y)+2(4x+y)=-15x+8x-9y+2y=-7x-7y=-7(x+y)=P(x+y)$.
More generally, any $(a,b)=(a,-\frac{2}{3}a)$ and $P(t)=\frac{7a}{3}t$ are yielding:
$a(5x+3y)-\frac{2}{3}a(4x+y)=\frac{7a}{3}(x+y)=P(x+y)$

---

**A generalization:**
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, for example $k=\mathbb{C}$.
Let $f,g,h_1,h_2 \in k[x,y]$, $g \neq h_i$, satisfy the following two conditions:
(1) $(f,g)$ is a maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$;
(2) $(f,h_1,h_2)$ is a maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$.

**Claim 2:** There exist $a,b,c,d \in k$, at least one of $\{a,b\}$ is nonzero, at least one of $\{c,d\}$ is nonzero, and $P(t),Q(t) \in k[t]$ such that
$ag+bh_1=P(f)$ and $cg+dh_2=Q(f)$.

Notice that for $h_1=h,h_2=0$ we reduce to claim 1, with $c=0$, $d \neq 0$, $Q(t)=0$.

> **Question 2:** Is claim 2 true?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but it seems that such $f,g,h$ satisfy: (1) $f,g$ is an automorphic pair and (2) $f,h$ is an automorphic pair. So $Jac(f,ag)=1$ and $Jac(f,bh)=1$ for some $a,b \in k^*$. Then $Jac(f,ag-bh)=0$, hence by a nice known result $ag-bh \in k[f]$, and we are done ("taking $\tilde{b}=-b$"). The nice known result is Theorem 1 in the following paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243065959_Younger_Mates_and_the_Jacobian_Conjecture

Comment: Actually no: $f=x-1,g=xy$ is maximal $(x-1,xy)=(x-1,y)$, but $x-1,xy$ is not an automorphic pair, $k[x-1,xy] \subsetneq k[x,y]$, but $k(x-1,xy)=k(x,y)$.

Comment: $f=xy, g=x-1, h=y-1$ is a counterexample: $(xy,x-1)=(x-1,y)$ and $(xy,y-1)=(x,y-1)$, but $a(x-1)+b(y-1) \notin k[xy]$.

Comment: Therefore, maybe we should require that $f$ is, in addition, an automorphic image, so the above counterexample with $f=xy$ is not relevant anymore.

Comment: I wonder if $f-\alpha \in (g-\beta, h-\gamma)$, but probably no. I guess that $xy \in (x,y)$ was just a coincidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Let
$$f=x, \quad g=y+xy^2, \quad h=y+1+xy^3.$$
Then
$$
(f,g)=(x,y)\quad\text{and}\quad (f,h)=(x,y+1)
$$
are maximal ideals of $k[x,y]$, but for all $a,b\in k$ not both zero, you find that $$ag+bh\not\in k[f]=k[x].$$

Comment: Should say, for all $a,b\in k$, $a,b$ not both zero.

Comment: you are right, I changed it